# How to recognize the first element in Objective-C style enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, fast-enumeration

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `NSNumbers`, I want to enumerate through all of them with Objective-C styled enumeration. Here's what I've done so far.

```
for ( NSNumber* number in array )
{
    //some code
}
```

I want to be able to recognize the first object fast, I am able to do this of course,

```
if ( [array indexOfObject:number] == 0 )
{
    //if it's the first object
}
```

Is there any way to do this faster? There's of course the old-fashioned C style way, and remove the object from array first, and then put it back after enumeration. Just want to know if there's a better technic.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a method that provides the index of the object currently being enumerated:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx == 0) {
        // this is the first object
    }
}];
```

Or if you simply want to access the first object of an array:

```
id obj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

or with the new Objective-C style/syntax:

```
id obj = array[0];
```

Comment: I am always so confused when I see the new Objective-C array indexing syntax... and I have Java/C++ background.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is faster than accessing and comparing the first array element:

```
BOOL firstIteration = YES;
for (NSNumber *number in array) {
    if (firstIteration) {
        // Handle first iteration
        firstIteration = NO;
    }
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fast enumeration you cant alter the array. So if you want to remove you have to use old style `for(;;)` loop.

To find the first object simply use `[array objectAtIndex:0]`